# Django test view issue

Tags: python, django, testing, view, get

i'm trying to test a view in my django project. I can't get the context from that view.
i'm working in the shell. I type:

```
>>> from django.test.client import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> c.login(username='Test', password='test')
True
>>> response = c.get(reverse('lista_categorie'))
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response.context['categorie']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have a variable 'category' that i give to the template as context, so i cannot understand why the context is empty. The status code is ok, and also the content corrisponds to the template.
This is the view:

```
def lista_categorie(request):
   categorie = Categoria.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('view_categories.html', {
    'categorie': categorie,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code of the view?

Comment: ok, i posted the view, it's very short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer is wrong. Here's the solution from http://jazstudios.blogspot.com/2011/01/django-testing-views.html, add this line so you can access context during tests:

```
>>> django.test.utils.setup_test_environment()
```

I haven't test this myself, you could test it.

Comment: I think that it is in the context, cause i can use that in the template, and i get the same error with your solution.